# TFS - deployment group servers go offline after disconnect remote control

Tags: tfs

I have servers in deployment group in TFS that run UI tests. 
When i mstsc them and close the connection, the user is logging off and my server goes offline in the TFS deployment group so i can't run UI tests on it.

Comment: Could you make sure the remote server still online, the disconnection may shut down or  hibernate your remote server machine.

Answer (score 2):

A deployment group is a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. Deployment groups represent the **physical environments**.

In effect, a deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool.

As for how to provision agents for deployment groups, you need to [run the installation script on the target servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/howto-provision-deployment-group-agents?view=vsts#run-the-installation-script-on-the-target-servers). First double check the machine is not shut down or hibernate.

Also make sure your agent service is running, the following image is a successful online machine for a deployment group:

[image]

Besides, if you have set up the proxy authentication for the machine or firewall, try to remove the proxy/temporarily disabled the firewall and try again. If nothing else works, try to reinstall the agent. It maybe some configuration issue.